# Open statement and Predicates (Discrete Math)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

### Logical Questions:

Is an open statement the same as a predicate ? Or is predicate referring to the notation of an open statement ?

```
Reference: P(x) or Q(x, y), etc are also called predicates.
```

Some clarification would be helpful.

Comment: Yes; an [Open formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_formula) is a formula that contains at least one free variable. See also [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)#Simplified_overview)

Comment: So predicate is not the notation P(x) ? In other words, predicate means open statement ?

Comment: Usually the language for *predicate logic* has predicate letters: $P(x), Q(x,y)$, etc. See e.g. [First-order logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#2).

Comment: Ok then I believe an open statement (not having a truth value) is another way of saying predicate which is not a proposition/statement (having a truth value).